# Word Prediction App using too much Shiny memory?

Tags: r, memory, shiny

I would greatly appreciate any feedback the community might offer regarding the issue I am having with my Word Prediction Shiny APP Code for the JHU Capstone Project.

The server.R and UI.r code run correctly locally. When I upload to shinyapps.io I run out of memory. I have provided the server and UI code as well as the log from Shiny below.

Suspected Root Cause: I believe the issue is the large text files that were used to create the corpus and then the prediction function...they are uploading to shiny as well.

I suspect that I need to exclude the large txt files from being uploaded to shiny by writing code that does not require them *after* the corpus_train has been created.

Is my assumption correct? If so, how do I write that into my code?
Or, am I off-base and there is another solution?

Things I've tried:

1. writing rm (raw text files) in the code after they have been sub-setted for the corpus:
   This caused the app to fail because it was looking for those files (en_US.blogs.txt, en_US.twitter.txt, en_US.news.txt)
2. writing rm(all files except the "corpus_train" - which is used for the prediction
   This caused the app to fail because it was looking for not only the large txt files mentioned in #1, but also the combined_sample and twit/news/blog sample files
3. Creating a new project that only houses the APP and its environment.
4. Read numerous similar question on Stackflow but did not see one that I could apply to my situation.

Much appreciated in advance for the communities help!

````
    ui.R
    library(shiny)
    library(sbo)
    library(processx)
    
    
    
    shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
            
            headerPanel("Predicitve Text APP"),
            sidebarPanel(
                    textInput("text", label = h3("Text input"), value = "Enter text..."),
                    
                    
                    
            ),
            
            mainPanel(
                    h4("Predicted Words:"),
                    verbatimTextOutput("result_output"),
    
                    
                    
                    h6("This APP generates three predicted next words based on the text you input. 
                       The prediction algorithm relies on word frequencies in the English twitter, 
                       blogs, and news datasets at:"),
                    h6(a("http://www.corpora.heliohost.org/")),
                    br(),
                    h6("Created April 2021 as part of my Captsone project for the 
                    Data Science Specialization provided by Johns Hopkins University and Coursera.
                    All code can be located on GitHub at:") ,
                    h6(a("https://github.com/themonk99/predictive.git"))
                    
            )
            
            
    ))
    ```server.r
    ##setwd("C:/Users/themo/OneDrive/Data Science JHU/Capstone/RHays_Shiny_Capstone")
    
    blog <- readLines("en_US.blogs.txt", warn=FALSE, encoding="UTF-8")
    twit <- readLines("en_US.twitter.txt", warn=FALSE, encoding="UTF-8")  
    news <- readLines("en_US.news.txt", warn=FALSE, encoding="UTF-8")
    
    twit_sample <- sample(twit, length(twit)*.10)
    news_sample <- sample(news, length(news)*.10)
    blog_sample <- sample(blog, length(blog)*.10)
    
    combined_sample <- c(twit_sample, blog_sample, news_sample)
    combined_sample <- iconv(combined_sample, "UTF-8","ASCII", sub="")
    length(combined_sample)
    
    
    corpus_train <- sbo_predictor(object = combined_sample, 
                                  N = 3, 
                                  dict = target ~ 0.75,
                                  .preprocess = sbo::preprocess,  
                                  EOS = ".?!:;", 
                                  lambda = 0.4, 
                                  L = 3L, 
                                  filtered = 
    )
    
    
    
    
    
    
    server <- function(input, output) {
            
            output$result_output <-renderText({
                    predict(corpus_train,input$text)
            })
    }
    
    ```

    2021-04-29T11:23:10.973363+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: httpuv version: 1.5.5
    2021-04-29T11:23:10.973342+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: shiny version: 1.6.0
    2021-04-29T11:23:10.973399+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: rmarkdown version: (none)
    2021-04-29T11:23:10.973407+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: knitr version: (none)
    2021-04-29T11:23:10.973412+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: jsonlite version: 1.7.2
    2021-04-29T11:23:10.973442+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: RJSONIO version: (none)
    2021-04-29T11:23:10.973312+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: Server version: 1.8.6.1
    2021-04-29T11:23:10.973449+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: htmltools version: 0.5.1.1
    2021-04-29T11:23:10.973617+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: Using pandoc: /opt/connect/ext/pandoc/2.11
    2021-04-29T11:23:11.175095+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
    2021-04-29T11:23:11.179051+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: 
    2021-04-29T11:23:11.179052+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: Starting R with process ID: '209'
    2021-04-29T11:23:11.212694+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: 
    2021-04-29T11:23:11.212696+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:42961
    2021-04-29T11:23:31.691484+00:00 shinyapps[system]: Out of memory!
    2021-04-29T11:23:34.451176+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: Running on host: 6c927e59cf13
    2021-04-29T11:23:34.456391+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: R version: 4.0.2
    2021-04-29T11:23:34.456489+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: knitr version: (none)
    2021-04-29T11:23:34.456381+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: Server version: 1.8.6.1
    2021-04-29T11:23:34.456391+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: LANG: en_US.UTF-8
    2021-04-29T11:23:34.456490+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: jsonlite version: 1.7.2
    2021-04-29T11:23:34.456397+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: shiny version: 1.6.0
    2021-04-29T11:23:34.456417+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: httpuv version: 1.5.5
    2021-04-29T11:23:34.641854+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
    2021-04-29T11:23:34.645882+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: Starting R with process ID: '233'
    2021-04-29T11:23:34.645881+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: 
    2021-04-29T11:23:34.456457+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: rmarkdown version: (none)
    2021-04-29T11:23:34.456510+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: htmltools version: 0.5.1.1
    2021-04-29T11:23:34.675822+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: 
    2021-04-29T11:23:34.456510+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: RJSONIO version: (none)
    2021-04-29T11:23:34.456666+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: Using pandoc: /opt/connect/ext/pandoc/2.11
    2021-04-29T11:23:34.675824+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:41970
    2021-04-29T11:23:54.728500+00:00 shinyapps[system]: Out of memory!
    2021-04-29T11:38:45.935720+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: Running on host: 6c927e59cf13
    2021-04-29T11:38:45.941654+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: Server version: 1.8.6.1
    2021-04-29T11:38:45.941664+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: LANG: en_US.UTF-8
    2021-04-29T11:38:45.941694+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: shiny version: 1.6.0
    2021-04-29T11:38:45.941669+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: R version: 4.0.2
    2021-04-29T11:38:45.941744+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: rmarkdown version: (none)
    2021-04-29T11:38:46.147771+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: 
    2021-04-29T11:38:45.941756+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: jsonlite version: 1.7.2
    2021-04-29T11:38:46.181887+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: 
    2021-04-29T11:38:45.941755+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: knitr version: (none)
    2021-04-29T11:38:45.941947+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: Using pandoc: /opt/connect/ext/pandoc/2.11
    2021-04-29T11:38:45.941703+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: httpuv version: 1.5.5
    2021-04-29T11:38:45.941788+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: htmltools version: 0.5.1.1
    2021-04-29T11:38:45.941781+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: RJSONIO version: (none)
    2021-04-29T11:38:46.143977+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: Using jsonlite for JSON processing
    2021-04-29T11:38:46.181888+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: Listening on http://127.0.0.1:35991
    2021-04-29T11:38:46.147772+00:00 shinyapps[4050847]: Starting R with process ID: '486'
    2021-04-29T11:39:06.539298+00:00 shinyapps[system]: Out of memory!
````

Comment: You are loading the files into memory for each session, its not necessary. Load it once above `server.R` or in a `global.R`. Moreover, you should already serve the saved models to the users, what you're doing is re-computing all the unnecessary work!

Comment: Thanks, Pork Chop.....using a global.R solved the memory problem....much appreciated.